# clone form with angular js

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I am trying to create a form with some details, at the end of the form I am trying to create a button "add new form". this button will clone the same form at the bottom and each form will have save button.
What is the best way to do it with angularjs? how I can do it with one controller, so it will know to what form I am doing submit (save)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an array in the controller defining the forms and use an ng-repeat to render the forms:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="form in forms">
        <hr/>
        <form name="myForm" ng-init="name = form.name">
            {{name}}
            <input name="myInput" type="text" ng-model="myInputValue"></input>
            <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="saveForm(this)" ng-disabled="!myForm.$dirty"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <input type="button" value="Create form" ng-click="createForm()"></input>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller('MyController', 
['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.forms = [{name: "form1"}];

    $scope.createForm = function(){
        $scope.forms.push({name: "form" + ($scope.forms.length + 1)});
    };

    $scope.saveForm = function(formScope){
        alert("Save called for " + formScope.name + ", myInputValue = " + formScope.myInputValue);            
    };
}]
```

);

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfvjv0uv/2/

Normally the formController is assigned to the scope but ng-repeat creates a child scope that we supply in the save method.